# In SQL How to iterate through a list of value in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "titles" which has the following value:

```
id   title  time
1    ABC    1-1-2021
2    EEE    1-1-2021
3    ABC    1-1-2020
4    123    2-1-2020
```

Now I want to select the record from this table with the giving list, e.g.:

```
let title_to_search = [ABC, 123]
```

Order by "time" column in DESC

I want to get the following result after searching table "title":

```
id   title  time
1    ABC    1-1-2021
4    123    2-1-2020
```

I have tried the following state:

```
select * from titles where title in title_to_search order by time DESC
```

The result is

```
id   title  time
1    ABC    1-1-2021
3    ABC    1-1-2020
4    123    2-1-2020
```

It is caused by id "3" also has title value "ABC". However, what I want is to iterate through the list, which means if "ABC" is already used in where clause, it should not be used again, therefore, record "1" should be selected, and "3" should not be selected, and 4 should be selected.

How can I write such a SQL statement?

I am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Following will work on sample data, with all extra data:

Select * from titles where id in (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM TITLES WHERE TITLE IN TITLE_TO_SEARCH GROUP BY TITLE)

Comment: Thanks but you are missing the column "time", if I simply add "time" into select, I will get the error: [Code: 1055, SQL State: 42000]  Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'TITLES.time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This should work :: Select * from titles where id in (SELECT MIN(ID)  FROM TITLES WHERE TITLE IN TITLE_TO_SEARCH GROUP BY TITLE)

Comment: No it doesn’t. Time needs to be aggregated. Use * won’t be able to get away from it. Also the logic is sort by time which isn’t necessarily related to ID which you are doing MIN(ID)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand meaning of time needs to be aggregated. The where clause sub query gets your the minimum of id grouped on title, if you need to be aggregated on time add that in sub query group by cluase after title. Then you select full row based on that ID. Can you post the query and result you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
SELECT a.*
FROM titles a
WHERE a.title IN ( 'ABC', '123' )
AND NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT 1
 FROM titles b
 WHERE b.title = a.title
 AND b.id < a.id
)
```

`b.id < a.id` could change according to your requirement, probably by `time`?

**About Performance**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM titles a WHERE a.title IN ( 'A2617', 'A6983' );
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       33 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from titles;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   707280 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT a.* FROM titles a WHERE a.title IN ( 'A2617', 'A6983' ) AND NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1  FROM titles b  WHERE b.title = a.title  AND b.id < a.id );
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref          | rows | filtered | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | range | _Idx1         | _Idx1 | 32      | NULL         |   33 |   100.00 | Using index condition                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,_Idx1 | _Idx1 | 32      | test.a.title |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Not exists; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------+------+----------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT a.* FROM titles a WHERE a.title IN ( 'A2617', 'A6983' ) AND NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1  FROM titles b  WHERE b.title = a.title  AND b.id < a.id );
+--------+-------+------------+
| id     | title | time       |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 404071 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 397458 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
+--------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT a.* FROM titles a WHERE a.title IN ( 'A2617', 'A6983' );
+--------+-------+------------+
| id     | title | time       |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 404071 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 495677 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 505974 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 522148 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 523088 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 545776 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 546174 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 565224 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 594082 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 634224 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 663641 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 684980 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 727136 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 733046 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 738378 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 747396 | A2617 | 2021-12-14 |
| 397458 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 398483 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 416826 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 418081 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 426902 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 454826 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 479057 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 486494 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 492336 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 515798 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 570730 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 587073 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 627372 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 672636 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 699460 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 722743 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
| 747387 | A6983 | 2021-12-14 |
+--------+-------+------------+
33 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks but the performance of this approach is a bit slow. It is even slower than I use Java code to iterator through array “titles” to make multiple database query.

Comment: It's not fair to compare the performance between pure SQL and application code. SQL is for general purpose, and highly dependent on the index settings, while your application code knows exactly the business logic, it is better choice sometimes.

Comment: @ZhangZhan and in this particular case, if `id` is primary key and title is also indexed, adding `NOT EXISTS` clause does not cost